# How can we sync two canvas element on separate pages

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am situation where i need to copy canvas on another page, both those pages are connected with socket.io so i've communication channel.

i as far as i my research said that i can use `getImageData` to get pixel data and send to another page so that page will draw this canvas, and i'll keep sending this in interval so any changes will be synced as well..
(right now i writing code for managing 20x20 pixel blocks and whatever block changed that will copied to another page.)

Sync means i'll also need changes to be sync.

is there any better solution? to sync only things are changed in last moment or without using `getImageData`.

[this canvas is not mine it will be not in my control, because i am implementing co browsing solution so on agent side i'll render canvas which will be in my control.]

Comment: Instead of using intervals, send data only when `draw` operation takes place...

Comment: Yes sure i'll look at that as well.. even i'll use combination of both. because there can be too much draws within second..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Transporting the full canvas content with each emit is resource intensive & inefficient.**

Imagine sending a full 300x300px image to convey a single 1x1px rect drawn onto the canvas!

Instead, **serialize each set of drawing commands** (==each `beginPath` through its ending `fill` / `stroke`). You can use tokens to represent each drawing command.

For example...

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,50);
ctx.lineTo(150,100);
ctx.lineTo(50,100);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle='red';
ctx.fill();
```

... can be tokenized as:

```
var set1=[
    ['m',100,50],
    ['l',150,100],
    ['l',50,100],
    ['z'],
    ['fs','red'],
    ['f'],
    ['sequence',myOrder++],
    ['timestamp',performance.now()]
];
```

Of course, you can custom tokenize any complex command sets that are specific to your design. For example, you might have a single token that moves an entire 20x20 pixel block.

You can `JSON.toString` this tokenized command set and broadcast it to other clients (==other pages).

When a client receives a message they can rehydrate the command set with `JSON.parse` and process it on their own canvas.

A few notes to get you started:

- Emits can be lost so the `sequence` and `timestamp` fields can be used to request missing packets and to properly order packets. You can do peer-to-peer packet management, but it's easier to have the server handle packet management.
- Some canvas actions are not easily serializable. In particular, pixel manipulations with `getImageData` are not easily serializable (including 3rd party image filters using getImageData).
- In practice, you will sometimes need to "hard reset" all canvases to a "last known good" content-state. You could do this by having all canvases clear themselves and reissuing all command sets since the-beginning-of-time. To be more efficient, have the server occasionally cache an image of the last-known-good canvas (and any command sets issued after the known good). This way you can hard-reset if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how big your canvas is and how often you are drawing, it might be cheaper to just use `canvas.toBlob` or `canvas.toDataURL`and send the entire canvas.

Checking your entire canvas for changes using `getImageData` can be quite expensive since you have to iterate over every pixel. If you're changing most of the canvas each time, I'd at least test sending the entire canvas using `canvas.toDataURL` to send a base64 encoded version.