# Streaming performance - Canvas vs <img>?

Tags: javascript, websocket, html5-canvas, streaming

I'm developing an application that requires constant streaming of images over a webSocket connection at a minimum of 30 frames per second.

I've run into a bit of a performance issue and am looking to optimize the best I can.

I was wondering what the performance differences would be between using a constantly updating image (like so`<img src="someDynamicallyUpdatingBase64Image" />` vs drawing the image to a canvass (`canvs.drawImage(someDynamicallyUpdatingImage, 0, 0, 640, 480)`)

To add some context, the images being sent to the client are being taken by a camera located server-side (think of an IP-Camera setup). We are only able to poll the camera for one individual image at a time, but this process can be done very quickly. The issue is that the client has to receive a buffer of bytes, encode the bytes into a base64 string (we're currently using the `<img src=xyz>` method), and have the dom redraw the image. This process is fairly lengthy and has caused quite a large deal of latency.

Comment: In order to draw it to a canvas, you first need to load the image in an image object so... Stream it as a video instead ;-)

Comment: To detail out @Kaiido's comment, you can use a `video` element as an image source to canvas's `drawImage(videoElement,0,0)`. The canvas will draw a snapshot of the current video frame. You can repeat the `drawImage` in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop to stream the video to the canvas.

Comment: I see you are using websockets. Are you doing a whiteboard app? If yes, then instead of trying to pass the entire canvas content (with .toDataURL) you can reduce the payload size dramatically by only transmitting each new incremental change in the canvas. See [this previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552350/how-can-we-sync-two-canvas-element-on-separate-pages/35563816#35563816) to get started.

Comment: To add some context, the images being sent to the client are being taken by a camera located server-side (think of an IP-Camera setup). We are only able to poll the camera for one individual image at a time, but this process can be done very quickly. The issue is that the client has to receive a buffer of bytes, encode the bytes into a base64 string (we're currently using the `<img src=xyz>` method), and have the dom redraw the image. This process is fairly lengthy and has caused quite a large deal of latency.

Comment: @JacobPersi. I see ... your encode / decode cycle is lengthy. You might buffer some frames to avoid breaks. If possible, use Kaiido's suggestion and stream your feed as video.

Comment: strings are slow. I wonder if you could, instead, 1) use get/putImageData and deal only with bytes or 2) send a jpeg.

Comment: @JacobPersi Why would you use base64!?  There is no reason for this.