# Stream base64 image - img vs canvas tags

Tags: html, image, canvas, websocket, base64

I need to stream base64 via websocket from server to client, is there any huge (or any) performance difference between using img or canvas elements in this case?

I tried to look for similar questions, such as this one:

[Streaming performance - Canvas vs <img>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798650/streaming-performance-canvas-vs-img)

But I didn't get an answer from there.

Comment: Did you read the comments there? In order to draw an image to a canvas, you need to load it from an `<img>` element. There can't be any benefit in using a canvas in such configuration, it's like if you were asking if when on a ferry, it's faster to be in a red car or a blue one. Just the same, the boat is responsible for the duration of the journey. Now, streaming still images at high rate is never a good idea, and that's why video is preferred. So if you are able to change your configuration so that you stream a video instead, then do so.

Comment: Why would you use base64 for this?  You're just adding 33% overhead to the bandwidth, not to mention a total waste of CPU on both ends.