# save a canvas object as json

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas

How would I serialize a canvas object, like the one below?

```
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
            context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 7;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();
```

Since it's interacting with the canvas context procedurally (is that the right terminology?) I don't think it's possible. But I would like to save objects like this so that it would be easier to manipulate them.

I mean how could I create two items like the one above, but just modifying the x,y starting positions? All I can think of is `eval` but I know that would horribly slow down drawing on the canvas.

Comment: serializing produces a string. you wouldn't need to json-ify that string unless you plan to use it in a json context, e.g. sending it through an ajax request, and even then you could just have `JSON.stringify({data:var_with_serialized_object})`

Comment: I would save the data from the object, no the object  (canvas) itself, so later on you call the information to reproduce the original canvas... but well is just the approach I believe would be more practical...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to reposition your drawing without fussing with each of the original coordinates, just use `context.translate` which moves the canvas [0,0] origin to any desired position on the canvas.

```
function draw(offsetX,offsetY){
    // translate the [0,0] origin of the canvas to [offsetX,offsetY]
    context.translate(offsetX,offsetY);

    // draw the original rectangle (no changes are required to any coordinates
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
    context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 7;
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();

    // always clean up! Reverse the translation
    context.translate(-offsetX,-offsetY);
}
```

If you want to send your original canvas commands to a different device then you must serialize the context drawing commands. See this previous [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552350/how-can-we-sync-two-canvas-element-on-separate-pages/35563816#35563816) showing how to save canvas drawing commands to a string. That string can be sent elsewhere (f.ex using AJAX or websockets) and then the receiving device can "replay" the commands.

Answer (score 2):

The `context.getImageData()` is the function that you are looking for. It will return an `ImageData` object from the data on a canvas ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)). It's syntax is as follows:

```
ImageData ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh);
```

So, if you want to save and serialize the data from a canvas, you would use the following code:

```
var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height).data;
```

Now the `.data` property on an `ImageData` object is an `Uint8ClampedArray`, which is basically a big list of all the colors of a canvas. However you choose to serialize it isn't important.

---

Let's say that you've received one of the serialized canvas "messages" and want to put it back onto a canvas. No problem, all you need is `context.putImageData()`:

```
context.putImageData(message.data, 0, 0);
```

This will "paste" the data from the first canvas onto the second one.

Good Luck!